If God existed, would He exist for no reason?
Why would He exist rather than something else such as a godless universe or simply nothing? How have theologians tried to answer this question in the past?
I have read that because God is eternal or timeless, He may not have a beginning. Does this mean He needs no explanation?

See e.g. Faith as well as Natural Theology and Natural Religion.

And see Principle of Sufficient Reason for Spinoza, Priciples: "Nothing exists of which it cannot be asked, what is the cause (or reason) [causa (sive ratio)], why it exists." wrt  Descartes’ view according to which God does not need a cause in order to exist, but there is a reason why God does not need a cause."

Which god? There are so many. And why only consider male gods?

@tkruse whether pagan or classically theistic, the Gods that get assigned names that mean God are almost all, among other things that personal influence which acts upon nature to cause nature to bring forth life and which dominates and subdues nature to create conditions amenable to life. This doesn't necessarily make God male even in ancient mythology.  (E.G. in Deuteronomy 32:18 God is both father and mother of humanity or Israel.) But it does make him obviously masculine in that God's interaction with the rest of reality is analogous to the male sexual role and the male gender role.

@gs the Question said 'He'.

I do agree however that it would help to specify which God(s) is/are being asked about.

@ScottRowe 'He' is in fact the masculine pronoun in English, yes!

@gs tkruse was addressing the Question and for some reason you came in and addressed tkruse. Now I'm addressing you, to say that you are addressing the wrong thing.

One common explanation given by theologians is that God must exist, necessarily. There are various versions of this argument, such as Anselm's ontological argument.
It should be obvious that not everyone finds these arguments compelling, but some people do.

What is the reason for a seed to become a tree? The tree is the expression/manifestation of a seed. In the same way the world is the expression/manifestation of God (whatever God). The reason God exists, is that you cannot have something out of nothing. God is an (active) abstraction, Each religion/philosophy, attributes to God a different level of abstraction, sometimes God may be personified.
The reason and the explanation of the seed becoming a tree, starts inside the seed. A letter is written by a pen, A child is born by a mother, The world is creater by God: it is so simple, accept it.
